# Wrong InverseLaplaceTransform?

Tags: integral-transforms

Is this a bug?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5B1%2FSqrt%5Bt%5D%2C+t%2C+x%5D

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[t],t,x]


1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[x])
```

Comment: `1/Sqrt[t] == 
 LaplaceTransform[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[t], t, x], x, t]` Looks correct.